# PHP connect to SQL not giving error message

Tags: php, sql, ado

I am trying to use PHP to connect to my SQL database using

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
```

I am trying to run a try/catch to make sure in case an error is thrown that I am able to capture the error.
So I am faking an error on the page, but instead of giving me an error the script just stops at that point and the page doesn't continue.

I'm looking for a way to make sure to display or notify me of the problem. Something like the equivalent of causing a 500 page to throw.

This is what my script looks like now. Notice, I put an extra single quote in the insert statement just to cause an error so I can test it.
The `echo` 'after', does not show up on the page.

```
//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
or die("Cannot start ADO");

//define connection string, specify database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";  PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;
$conn->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query =  "INSERT INTO dbo.EventOnlineAppsIndividual (EventId, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, [State], Zip, Email) VALUES (". $_POST['id'] .", ''" . $_POST['FirstName'] ."','". $_POST['LastName']."', '". $_POST['Address']."','".$_POST['City']."', '". $_POST['State']."', '". $_POST['Zip']."', '".$_POST['email'] . "')" ;
echo $query . "<br before:<br>";
var_dump($query);

//execute the SQL statement and return records
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
echo "after";
```

Comment: the `echo $query` works?

Comment: the first echo works.. After execute, nothing happens

Comment: The problem I am running into is I am trying to set up a catch system in case something goes wrong but it's not catching any error.
What do I have to do to display an error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not quite understanding the question. Below would be your code in a try-catch block. I'm throwing an error if the execute method fails. It will output the string 'Query did not execute'.

```
try{
//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
or die("Cannot start ADO");

//define connection string, specify database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";  PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;
$conn->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query =  "INSERT INTO dbo.EventOnlineAppsIndividual (EventId, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, [State], Zip, Email) VALUES (". $_POST['id'] .", ''" . $_POST['FirstName'] ."','". $_POST['LastName']."', '". $_POST['Address']."','".$_POST['City']."', '". $_POST['State']."', '". $_POST['Zip']."', '".$_POST['email'] . "')" ;
echo $query . "<br before:<br>";
var_dump($query);

//execute the SQL statement and return records
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
if(!$rs) {
  throw new Exception('Query did not execute')
}
//This echo still wont be hit. unless you move it to the catch block.
echo "after";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
```